Please explain the relation between fragsize and PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY
I am working on tuning record PulseAudio stream for my application and there are some things I can't understand.
According to PulseAudio API, pa_buffer_attr::fragsize field is used to configure maximum audio chunk size served by PulseAudio record stream, that is my application will receive no more than pa_buffer_attr::fragsize audio data bytes in one read.
There is also PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY flag, which makes PulseAudio to use the pa_buffer_attr::fragsize value as a desired latency of PulseAudio record stream.
When I configure the record stream with this flag enabled and pa_buffer_attr::fragsize set to 20ms, I get different results for different devices, depending on audio hardware.
For example, for one of my devices I get 100ms actual latency (read with pa_stream_get_latency() function) and 3200 bytes of audio data in every read, which according to my audio specification (16kHz sample rate, 2B sample size) is exactly 100ms worth of audio data if PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY is set, no matter what the value of pa_buffer_attr::fragsize is.
For another device with different audio hardware I get a latency roughly 10-20ms lower than requested, that is if pa_buffer_attr::fragsize is 20ms and PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY is set, the actual latency is 10ms and data is served in chunks of 10ms in every read.
There is following explanation I found online (source):

If PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY is set, then the tlength/fragsize parameters will be interpreted slightly differently than described above when passed to pa_stream_connect_record() and pa_stream_connect_playback(): the overall latency that is comprised of both the server side playback buffer length, the hardware playback buffer length and additional latencies will be adjusted in a way that it matches tlength resp. fragsize. Set PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY if you want to control the overall playback latency for your stream. Unset it if you want to control only the latency induced by the server-side, rewritable playback buffer. The server will try to fulfill the clients latency requests as good as possible. However if the underlying hardware cannot change the hardware buffer length or only in a limited range, the actually resulting latency might be different from what the client requested.

After I thorough reading of the explanation above, I need to clarify following points:

What exactly does latency mean for PulseAudio record stream?
I know that it must be the short period of delay (usually measured in milliseconds) between when an audio signal is captured by audio hardware and when it is served to my application.
What I don't understand is why when I set PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY, the size of audio chunks and the actual latency are the same. Does it mean something or is it just a coincidence? How pa_buffer_attr::fragsize and latency are related?

As per the examples I mentioned earlier, what does 100ms record stream latency mean in practice?
When my application received an audio chunk with 100ms worth of data and the latency is 100ms, does it mean that the last sample in that chunk was captured 100ms ago, but due to all of the latencies induced by PulseAudio and hardware received only now?

What is the actual meaning of pa_buffer_attr::fragsize when the PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY is set?
The explanation says that it is used to control the overall playback (I assume record too) latency for my stream. But what does overall latency of record stream mean in practice?

What is the actual meaning of pa_buffer_attr::fragsize when the PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY is unset?
The quote above says that it is used to control only the latency induced by the server-side, rewritable playback (I assume record too) buffer. But what does server-side latency mean in practice?


I tried to phrase my questions as clear as possible and highlight the points I don't understand, but if there is additional clarification needed please let me know.
